# Encountered " "<" "< "" at line 1, column 15. Was expecting: <IRIref>

Tags: sparql

Trying to use the query in the endpoint. The query was created in SPARQL. The error coming like

```
Encountered " "<" "< "" at line 1, column 15.
Was expecting:
    <IRIref> ...
```

Query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?Class ?Title ?Definition
WHERE {
?Value rdfs:label ?Class
FILTER regex(?Class, "Motion") .
?def rdfs:domain ?Value .
?def rdfs:label ?Title .
?def rdfs:comment ?Definition}
```

The url

```
http://localhost:3030/skosmos/query?query=
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?Class ?Title ?Definition
WHERE {
    ?Value rdfs:label ?Class
    FILTER regex(?Class, "Motion") .
    ?def rdfs:domain ?Value .
    ?def rdfs:label ?Title .
    ?def rdfs:comment ?Definition
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The specific line you showed us doesn't look wrong in itself. Can you show the full SPARQL query and also perhaps let us know which software you're using to execute the query? Please [edit] your question to add these details. And, as Thilina suggested above, have a look at [ask] for some tips on writing good questions.

Comment: @NaveenNatarajan The error message is clear enough, isn't it? You forgot the angle brackets in the prefix declaration.

Comment: Do you URL escape the query when you run it via HTTP request?

Comment: @AKSW No, I didn't forget the angle brackets.

Comment: Well, the error indicates exactly the position of it...`line 1 column 15` - how do you send the query to the client?

Comment: http://localhost:3030/skosmos/query?query=%20PREFIX%20rdfs:%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%20SELECT%20?Class%20?Title%20?Definition%20WHERE%20{%20?Value%20rdfs:label%20?Class%20FILTER%20regex(?Class,%20%22Motion%22)%20.%20?def%20rdfs:domain%20?Value%20.%20?def%20rdfs:label%20?Title%20.%20?def%20rdfs:comment%20?Definition%20} This is it

Comment: You need to put the whole URI into your question, properly code-fenced with Markdown, so we can look at it.  Note that SO has truncated and otherwise messed with it here in the comments...  (Also note that "the url" currently in your question is not a URL.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I took your original query, URL-encoded it with [one of many services and tools you might use, randomly selected from a web search](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/), and appended it to the start of what you had as "the URL", `http://localhost:3030/skosmos/query?query=` ... and you verified that this worked --

[`http://localhost:3030/skosmos/query?query=PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3FClass+%3FTitle+%3FDefinition%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A%3FValue+rdfs%3Alabel+%3FClass%0D%0AFILTER+regex%28%3FClass%2C+%22Motion%22%29+.%0D%0A%3Fdef+rdfs%3Adomain+%3FValue+.%0D%0A%3Fdef+rdfs%3Alabel+%3FTitle+.%0D%0A%3Fdef+rdfs%3Acomment+%3FDefinition%7D`](http://localhost:3030/skosmos/query?query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3FClass%20%3FTitle%20%3FDefinition%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3FValue%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FClass%0D%0AFILTER%20regex%28%3FClass%2C%20%22Motion%22%29%20.%0D%0A%3Fdef%20rdfs%3Adomain%20%3FValue%20.%0D%0A%3Fdef%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FTitle%20.%0D%0A%3Fdef%20rdfs%3Acomment%20%3FDefinition%7D)